# Create a simple Google Docs File in a Subfolder

Tags: google-drive-api

I am a beginner in Scripting and for my training I try to create a simple Google File in a subfolder:

```
function createFilesInSubFolder() {
    //This creates the Workingfolder
    var folder = DriveApp.createFolder('MyWorkingFolder');
    //This creates a file in the folder
    var file = folder.createFile('FileName','Text in the File',MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);
    //Mime.Typen: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type
}
```

The script gives me this error:

```
Ungültiges Argument: file.contentType (Zeile 6, Datei "Code")
```

The script works when I create a minetype JPEG or PLAIN_TEXT. Where is the trick to create a Google document direct in a subfolder? To create a file in the rootfolder works with the command `DocumentApp.create('GoogleStandardFileType')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of creating Google Docs, it uses DocumentApp or Drive API. And when Google Docs are created, there are 2 methods for creating it in a subfolder.

### Method 1

In this method, a document is created by `DocumentApp.create()` and changed the parents (folder) from initial folder (root folder) to `MyWorkingFolder`.

**Script :**

```
var doc = DocumentApp.create('FileName');
doc.getBody().editAsText().insertText(0, 'Text in the File');
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId());
var destfolder = DriveApp.createFolder('MyWorkingFolder');
var sourcefolder = file.getParents().next();
destfolder.addFile(file);
sourcefolder.removeFile(file);
```

### Method 2

In this method, a document is created by Drive API. In this case, when the document is created, the document is directly created to the subfolder `MyWorkingFolder`.

**Script :**

```
DocumentApp.openById(Drive.Files.insert({
    "title":    "FileName",
    "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.document",
    "parents":  [{"id": DriveApp.createFolder('MyWorkingFolder').getId()}]
}).id).getBody().editAsText().insertText(0, 'Text in the File');
```

**Note :**

When you use Drive API, please enable Drive API on Google API Console as follows.

1. In the script editor, select Resources > Cloud Platform Project
2. At the bottom of the dialog, click the link for the Google API Console.
3. In the console, click into the filter box and type part of the name of the API "Drive API", then click the name once you see it.
4. On the next screen, click Enable API.
5. Close the Developers Console and return to the script editor. Click OK in the dialog.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much - i think the Method 1 is the better way without not so much settings :). I have a lot to learn.

Comment: Hello, thanks for this info. I´m new on the portal. Thanks

Comment: Welcome. Thank you, too.